# BDD when testing a web service / API

Tags: web-services, api, testing, bdd

I am still trying to totally understand BDD and I am facing some doubts.
From my little experience, I have been using it to automate user acceptance test and I would like to know if it's possible to use it to test a web API, without UI.

In the past I've used BDD using the given-when-then jargon and mapping the steps to UI interactions. I've done this with Specflow in ASP.NET or cucumber/capybara in ruby on rails.
So for example we could have scenarios like this:

```
Given I am in the home page 
When I click login button 
Then I should see the login page
```

The current project I am working at is different. We are implementing an API based in web service which would be consumed by different type of clients. Like an iphone app, android app and an asp based web client. So our main focus is based in the back-end and just that.

In this case, the tests can't be faced from the UI point of view. So our end-to-end tests are based in our service endpoints. We pass some input arguments to a service calls and check the outputs. 
Can we do this using BDD? Is this right? 
or maybe it would be better to use a different thing like FitNesse? 
Hmm.. is using FitNesse doing BDD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do what your writing about in BDD. I'm not sure if those 2 links about testing of webservices with SpecFlow will help you but take a look on them if you haven't seen it yet.

http://codedetective.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/testing-webservices-with-specflow.html

http://www.creamdog.se/blog/2011/02/24/webservices-automated-tests-using-specflow-and-babelfish/

Comment: yes, definitely you can. Also this article speaks about BDD doing in different ways: from the UI, from the web services or from the controllers. http://skipoleschris.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/best-way-to-apply-bdd.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate), web service testing framework by [Intuit](https://www.intuit.com/). It's recently being **open sourced**. It has the capability of handling API dealing with HTML, JSON, XML, GraphQL queries and is built on top on [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/).

Simple intro here : https://medium.com/blueprint-by-intuit/karate-web-services-testing-made-simple-366e8eb5adc0#.qnpy5gagt

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote this question.. 
I have learn a lot about BDD and Spec by example in the last years. I have learnt that BDD is just a practice, not a tool itself.. I know that you can use BDD for the frontend, backend http backend, even unit test. The point of BDD is just to get a conversation between business and technical people, rather than automated testing (that's nice to have, but not a goal).
That's why I think this Karate tool is the wrong aproach. It makes test automation really easy, but you lose the power of talking to the business when you start using http terms.

Comment: @Asier Although Karate is based on Cucumber, it is not for BDD and the syntax just makes it easier to read. Karate has value as an automation tool and if you dismiss it just because it doesn't fit your idea of BDD, you may be missing out: [Yes, Karate is not *true* BDD](https://hackernoon.com/yes-karate-is-not-true-bdd-698bf4a9be39)

Comment: Hi Peter, still i think using gherkin syntax it's going to mislead many people. People relate gherkin with bdd, thus people will misleadingly think they are doing bdd when using karate. I'm not saying karate doesn't bring value, I'm just saying karate puts the focus on the wrong place - the automation.

Comment: @Asier so your argument is that Karate is bad because it will confuse people ? And I simply fail to understand how automation is the "wrong place" to focus on.  Anyway lets agree to disagree and let readers decide. Peace !